# Refreshing fragment - Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, fragment

With Xamarin and until Android 8 i was using:

```
 var ft =  FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
 ft.Detach(fragment).Attach(fragment).Commit();
```

to refresh a fragment. With Android 9 this code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Try `var ft = getSupportFragmentManager();`

Comment: You can try `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();` if it works please tell me.